# C++ Linux system() ouputs weird in combination with printf();

Tags: c++, linux, system, printf, cpu

I want to get the name of the CPU and the clock speed, in C++ on Linux. But so far, it's not working out well for me. Right now I'm using this piece of code:

```
printf("\033[1;32m[ OK ]\033[0m Initializing...\n");
printf("\033[1m[INFO]\033[0m CPU name: ");
system("grep -i --color 'model name' /proc/cpuinfo | uniq | sed -e 's/model name//' |    sed -e 's/: //' | sed -e 's/          //' | sed -e 's/@.*//'");
printf("\n");
printf("\033[1m[INFO]\033[0m CPU speed: ");
system("grep -i --color 'model name' /proc/cpuinfo | uniq | sed -e 's/.*@//'");
printf("\n");
```

Now, the desired output should be (on my machine) something like this:

```
[ OK ] Initializing...
[INFO] CPU name: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU X5365  
[INFO] CPU speed: 3.00GHz
```

But thats not what it gives me. It gives this weird structure:

```
[ OK ] Initializing...
     Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU X5365  
[INFO] CPU name: 
 3.00GHz
[INFO] CPU speed:
```

Does anyone know what to do with this? Tnx anyway.

Comment: Perhaps `popen` might be useful to you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to flush the output stream before you call `system`, otherwise the printed-out string can be buffered. Printing a `\n` flushes (assuming `stdout` is line-buffered, which will usually be the case if you're writing to a terminal), but printing a line without that doesn't necessarily flush.

Try adding:

```
fflush(stdout);
```

before your `system` calls.

(`fflush` is in `<cstdio>`.)

Comment: Is that "`\n` flushes" thing guaranteed from the system specifically?

Comment: @LucDanton No. In particular '\n' will not flush the stream if you are not writing to terminal.

Comment: @LucDanton: It's in POSIX for line-buffered streams (http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_05). Fully buffered streams are only required to flush on full buffer.

Comment: It's in the C standard (7.19.2 Streams, one of the bits that is also applicable to C++, even), so it also applies to non-POSIX systems.

Comment: @hvd: C99 says in the paragraph about stream buffering modes: "Support for these characteristics is implementation-defined, ..." (§7.19.3/3), which POSIX repeats, so it might actually not apply universally to C implementations or even POSIX :(